# Get data-field of above td cell

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a button that adds a row to a table. The table is editable on click (similar to one found here: http://www.9lessons.info/2011/03/live-table-edit-with-jquery-and-ajax.html)
However, I get my table data from a database. Each `<td>` has a `data-field` attribute that cooresponds with the `<td>'s` field name in the database. Now, in order for the added table row to be editable like the other rows, I need to mark the `<td>'s` `data-field` with the `data-field` from the cell directly above it. I have tried a few different methods but keep coming up short. Here is my add row script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        /*
        Add a new table row to the bottom of the table
    */

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".add").click(function()
        {
            $("#table").each(function()
            {
                var $table = $(this);
                var id=$('#table tr:last').attr('id');
                var $tr = $("#table").children('tr');
                var $th = $(this).closest('table').find('th').eq($(this).index());
                // Number of td's in the last table row
                var n = $('tr:last td', this).length;
                var tds = '<tr class="edit_tr" id="' + id++ + '">';

                for(var i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    tds += '<td class="edit_td"><input type="text" class="editbox" id="' +
                    id + '" data-field="' + $th + '"/>&nbsp;</td>';
                    console.log($th);
                }
                tds += '</tr>';
                //console.log(tds);
                if($('tbody', this).length > 0)
                {
                    $('tbody', this).append(tds);
                }else {
                    $(this).append(tds);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now, notice `var $th = $(this).closest('table').find('th').eq($(this).index());`. That is the closest I have gotten. However, I do not want to access by `th`. I want to access by data-field. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just go via the `$.attr('data-field);`

Comment: Because I do not know how to get the `data-field` of the cell above the one that's being created. I could possibly make an array of all the last `tr's` `data-fields` but I wouldn't know how to go about doing such a thing. I could then just do `array[i]` in my for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

`var $th = $(this).closest('table').find('th').last().attr('data-field');`

keep in mind I haven't tried this at all, but what you'd want to do is look for the last created `<th>` element

Comment: `//array
     for(var i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
      fieldArray.push($('.edit_tr:first').find('.edit_td').next().attr('data-field'));
     }
     console.log(fieldArray);`

I tried this and just get an array full the second data-field. Any ideas how to go to the next one?

Answer (score 0):

There is a CSS selector, and so too a valid jQuery selector for attributes. You can build one of these selectors on the fly like so:

`// Find the value of the field you're looking for

var currentDataField = $('#table tr:last [data-field]').data('field');`

// Construct a selector using that
var previous = currentDataField - 1;
var previousSelector = '[data-field=' + previous + ']';
var $previous = $(previousSelector);

$previous now holds the whatever item has the "previous" data-field. You will probably have to do some more DOM traversal to do what you want.

Let me know if you need clarification.

Comment: I am having trouble following your example and how it fits into my code. I have this: 

`currentDataField = $('.edit_tr:first').find('.edit_td').first().attr('data-field');
     for(var i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
      fieldArray.push(currentDataField);
      currentDataField = $('.edit_tr').find('.edit_td').nextAll().attr('data-field');
     }`

which seems to work almost right. It has an array the has the proper first and second elements but then the last x number of elements are the same as the second.

Comment: I see that the `currentDataField` in the loop must be going back to element 0 (or the first header) each time. How can I get it  to retain its position so that `.next()` gets the next element from the previous instead of the first. Thanks.